# Writing to json file in a for loop - python

Tags: python

I wrote the function as follows to save txt file in each iteration of for loop. I am calling the function called fun inside the loop. how can I save the result as a txt file? it creates file correctly but I want the name of file have txt at the end

```
ids = ["a1","a2","a3"]
def fun(id):
    results={}
    do something
    return results

for id in ids:
    final = fun(id)
    with open(id, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(final))
```

if I dont call the function, saving to txt file will look like this.

```
final = fun(id)
import json
with open('id.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(final))
```

Comment: Your function isn't fully written. Would you mind adding the full function? as well as giving more details to your use case? it's not very clear what the issue is.

Comment: I added the brief function, does it help?

Comment: function returns dictionary. but it only gets one single id, I want to run it for a list of id stored in ids

Comment: What is the issue here? It looks like your code should be creating some files which contain `json` text. Can you include a sample of `ids`? It looks like this should be a list of filenames.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: How do you know?

Comment: there is no issue, it creates  file correctly but I want the name of file have txt at the end

Comment: Ok, I see the update with a definition of `ids`. It looks like, at least, you should get a series of files containing the same string: `"{}"`

Comment: @quamrana I thought they were appending to the same file, like in the answe below

Comment: Did you mean: `with open(id+'.txt', 'w') as file:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need to edit is the name of your saved files.

```
import json

def fun(id):
    results = 'hello world'
    return results

ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for id in ids:
    final = fun(id)
    with open(f"{id}.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(final))
```

The past code will save "Hellow world" in 4 files named `1.txt`to `4.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For saving a json object in a text format you need to use the `json.dumps()` method that takes a dictionary. If you have an object:

```py
my_obj = {"foo" : "bar"}
```

you can pass that object to the dumps method as follows:

```py
import json

txt = json.dumps(my_obj)
```

The variable `txt` is now should be of `str` type, so you can simply write it into a txt file:

```py
with open("data.txt" , "w") as data_file:
    data_file.write(txt)
```

In your loop it will look like this:

```py
import json

def fun(id) -> dict:
    my_obj = {"foo" : "bar"}
    return my_obj

ids = [1,2,3,4]

for id in ids:
    final = fun(id)
    with open("data.txt") as data_file:
        data_file.write(final)
```

Comment: this will keep overwriting the same file, keeping only the last one